# Converting data in a Rails Migration using the model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Lets imagine we have an `Article` entity, with data imported from a legacy database. It contains an `appendix` column with type `integer`. This column is always filled with values `0`, `1` or `nil`, so we decide to call it `in_appendix` with type `boolean`. We want to preserve all existent data so we convert the data like this:

```
class ChangeTypeAppendixColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :article, :in_appendix, :boolean

    f  = Article.update_all({ in_appendix: false }, { appendix: nil })
    f += Article.update_all({ in_appendix: false }, { appendix: 0 })
    t  = Article.update_all({ in_appendix: true  }, { appendix: 1 })

    remove_column :article, :appendix
  end

  def down
    ...
  end
end
```

The problem is, if someday the `Article` model changes radically or ceases to exist, these migrations won't run anymore. My current solution is to create an `AuxArticle` class like this:

```
class AuxArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :article
end

class ChangeTypeAppendixColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :article, :in_appendix, :boolean

    f  = AuxArticle.update_all({ in_appendix: false }, { appendix: nil })
    f += AuxArticle.update_all({ in_appendix: false }, { appendix: 0 })
    t  = AuxArticle.update_all({ in_appendix: true  }, { appendix: 1 })

    remove_column :article, :appendix
  end

  def down
    ...
  end
end
```

It works but I would like to know about more elegant ways to keep existing data and at the same time prevent coupling between migrations and models.

Comment: hmmm... why not do this in raw sql or Arel then ? as a side note, you have to call `Article.reset_column_information` before using the model or your operations will fail.